# Передача данных через TCP

Tags: android, java, сокет

Привет всем.

Каким образом можно обмениваться данными между двумя машинами (в моем случае это будут два телефона на Android OS)?

Я сделал тестовый пример где с помощью класса `Socket` и `ServerSocket` обмениваюсь сообщениями...., но это все происходит через WiFi... Т.е ip используются локальные.. и по идее через 3G мои приложения уже видеть друг друга не будут....

Вопрос: как сделать отправку данных через интернет, а не через локалку?

Answer (score 1):

Надо делать свой сервер, обмениватсья данными через него.

Comment: А нельзя ли это делать напрямую, peer-to-peer например?

Comment: @Vadimcg в локальной сети одно из устройств может быть в роли сервака. Но в 3G не представляю как это сделать. Только сервак свой юзать.

Comment: А что посоветуете почитать по этому поводу?

Comment: @Vadimcg о том, как свой сервес написать, или о том, как с ним взаимодействовать ? )

Comment: @Vadimcg, Можно конечно настроить dynamic dns, скачать клиент, сделать domain. Но тогда 1 телефон будет сервером всегда. Если планируется использовать больше 2х устройств лучше сделать отдельный сервер.

Почитай как сделать веб сервер на PHP, на JSP ну или что там тебе больше нравится. Устройства могут получать от сервера адрес необходимого устройства и потом подключиться через сокет и взаимодействовать.

Comment: Ну я так и делаю, у меня вопрос стоит в другом, сейчас все на локалке работает, будет ли это работать через 3G.... Сейчас при каждом входе клиент посылает серверу порт и ip(текущий), и сервер в случае надобности выдает эти данные другим клиентам для связи...., но ведь этот ip локальный..., будет ли эта схема работать не на локалке?

Comment: @Vadimcg, будет только если у будет статичный ip адрес.